# go tool pprof interpretation

Tags: go, pprof, heap-profiling

I am using list command in go tool pprof to analyse heap profile. On using the list command I am expecting to see lines in source that allocates specified amount of memory. This is how my result looks like.

(pprof) list  getItems

Total: 259.09MB
ROUTINE ======================== ddb.(*ItemDL).getEvents in /bld/src/my-repo/ddb/item_process_dl.go

```
     0   322.15MB (flat, cum) 124.34% of Total
     .          .    201:       ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
     .          .    202:       //Limit:                     aws.Int64(1000),
     .          .    203:   }
     .          .    204:   if nil != lastEvaluatedKey {
     .          .    205:       params.SetExclusiveStartKey(lastEvaluatedKey)
     .   163.08MB    206:   }
```

//some more souce code

```
     .           .    266:          LaunchTS: qItem.LaunchTS + svcparam.TimeToBumpUp,
     .    21.01MB    267:       }
```

Why are the values pointing to lines having no source code and just `}`. How to interpret the above results ?

Comment: "I am expecting to see lines in source that allocates specified amount of memory." Your expectation is unwarranted, that's all. Profile data is best interpreted on the function level. Not on "source code line" (if this seems astonishing: Think of a loop unrolled by the compiler). The simples way "to interpret the above results" is by using the graph output of pprof, identifying functions with large allocations.

Comment: The "which line 'does the allocation'" question is something _you_ have to figure out by comparing what your function does and what calls show up in you functions allocation profile.

Comment: okay, thanks. any thoughts on what would be the correct use case for list command ?

Comment: First: You must understand that profiling is done by _sampling_ and only allocs that _got sampled_ will be a) counted in the profile (obvious) and b) have lines displayed. Maybe this is the culprit in understanding. Yes: If a line got sampled and contributed allocations it will be show. But is is "the other way around" as you seem to think of: It's not "show my source code and label each line with how much memory it allocates". It's sample the applications allocations and redistribute these allocations back up the callstack.